# Cant install capybara webkit on Mac

Tags: ruby, capybara

been trying to bundle using

```
QT_SELECT=5 bundle install
```

but keep running into this error

```
ridgedon@Ridges-MacBook-Pro webkit-server % QT_SELECT=5 bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 13.0.1
Using CFPropertyList 2.3.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using json 1.8.6
Using minitest 5.14.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.6
Using activesupport 4.2.4
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.7
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.4.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 4.2.4
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.4
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activejob 4.2.4
Using mime-types 2.99.3
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.4
Using activemodel 4.2.4
Using arel 6.0.4
Using activerecord 4.2.4
Using acts-as-taggable-on 3.5.0
Using acts_as_list 0.9.0
Using addressable 2.4.0
Using excon 0.45.4
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using fog-core 1.37.0
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using fog-json 1.0.2
Using ipaddress 0.8.0
Using xml-simple 1.1.5
Using fog-aliyun 0.1.0
Using fog-xml 0.1.3
Using fog-atmos 0.1.0
Using fog-aws 0.7.6
Using inflecto 0.0.2
Using fog-brightbox 0.9.0
Using fog-dynect 0.0.2
Using fog-ecloud 0.3.0
Using fog-google 0.1.0
Using fog-local 0.2.1
Using fog-powerdns 0.1.1
Using fog-profitbricks 0.0.5
Using fog-radosgw 0.0.4
Using fog-riakcs 0.1.0
Using fog-sakuracloud 1.4.0
Using fog-serverlove 0.1.2
Using fog-softlayer 1.0.2
Using fog-storm_on_demand 0.1.1
Using fog-terremark 0.1.0
Using fission 0.5.0
Using fog-vmfusion 0.1.0
Using fog-voxel 0.1.0
Using fog-xenserver 0.2.2
Using fog 1.36.0
Using thor 0.20.3
Using railties 4.2.4
Using javascript_dlog-rails 1.0.1
Using sass 3.4.19
Using jquery-fileupload-rails 0.4.6
Using simple_form 3.2.0
Using anaconda 2.0.2
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.0.3
Using aws-eventstream 1.0.2
Using aws-sigv4 1.1.0
Using jmespath 1.4.0
Using aws-sdk-core 2.11.257
Using aws-sdk-resources 2.11.257
Using aws-sdk 2.11.257
Using bcrypt 3.1.13
Using coderay 1.1.1
Using better_errors 2.1.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using bootstrap-datepicker-rails 1.4.0
Using kaminari 0.16.3
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using sprockets 3.4.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
Using rails 4.2.4
Using bootstrap-kaminari-views 0.0.5
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.5.1
Using mimemagic 0.3.3
Using carrierwave 0.11.2
Using mini_magick 4.10.1
Using remotipart 1.4.2
Using bootsy 2.1.0
Using bugsnag 6.8.0
Using uniform_notifier 1.10.0
Using bullet 5.6.1
Using byebug 6.0.2
Using colorize 0.7.7
Using net-ssh 3.0.1
Using net-scp 1.2.1
Using sshkit 1.7.1
Using capistrano 3.4.0
Using capistrano-bundler 1.1.4
Using capistrano-rails 1.1.3
Using xpath 2.1.0
Using capybara 2.5.0
Using launchy 2.4.3
Using capybara-screenshot 1.0.17
Fetching capybara-webkit 1.7.1
Installing capybara-webkit 1.7.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1
/Users/ridgedon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20201008-48198-i94z8h.rb extconf.rb
Info: creating stash file /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/.qmake.stash
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake -o Makefile.webkit_server
/Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/src/webkit_server.pro 'LIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib' ) &&
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.webkit_server
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 3
Command 'make' failed

current directory: /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1
make "DESTDIR=" clean
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake -o Makefile.webkit_server
/Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/src/webkit_server.pro 'LIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib' ) &&
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.webkit_server clean
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-clean-ordered] Error 3

current directory: /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1
make "DESTDIR="
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake -o Makefile.webkit_server
/Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/src/webkit_server.pro 'LIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib' ) &&
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.webkit_server
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 3

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/2.6.0/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.7.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.7.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  capybara-webkit
```

and whenever I run

```
gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.7.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

I get

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1
/Users/ridgedon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20201008-48386-1xgbddp.rb extconf.rb
Info: creating stash file /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/.qmake.stash
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake -o Makefile.webkit_server /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/src/webkit_server.pro 'LIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib' ) && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 3
Command 'make' failed

current directory: /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1
make "DESTDIR=" clean
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake -o Makefile.webkit_server /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/src/webkit_server.pro 'LIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib' ) && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.webkit_server clean
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-clean-ordered] Error 3

current directory: /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1
make "DESTDIR="
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake -o Makefile.webkit_server /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/src/webkit_server.pro 'LIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib' ) && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 3

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ridgedon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/2.6.0/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/gem_make.out
```

How can I fix this on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

capybara-webkit has gone EOL - It's not worth using anymore (replicates a really old browser).  Use Capybara with the Selenium driver and a headless browser, or with one of the direct to CDP drivers.

Comment: Is there a way to still use it even though it is outdated?

Comment: @ridge It MIGHT be possible to get it to compile but it's so far behind the current version of Capybara driver support and replicates a browser that's so old it's really not worth the effort